# function pointer gives me “redeclared as different kind of symbol” error

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dlsym

I want to decloare a function pointer as:

`char*(*palpr_recognize_rawimage)(OPENALPR*, unsigned char*, int, int, int, struct AlprCRegionOfInterest);`

which is for a function prototype declared as:

`char *openalpr_recognize_rawimage(OPENALPR *instance, unsigned char *pixelData, int bytesPerPixel, int imgWidth, int imgHeight, struct AlprCRegionOfInterest roi)`

but I get this error on compilation:

```
‘char* (* palpr_recognize_rawimage)(OPENALPR*, unsigned char*, int, int, int, AlprCRegionOfInterest)’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
             char*(*palpr_recognize_rawimage)(OPENALPR*, unsigned char*, int, int, int, struct AlprCRegionOfInterest);
                                                                                                                    ^
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid retyping a complex definition and possibly making an error is to use decltype.

So, after your function prototype you can have:

```
using PFN = decltype(&openalpr_recognize_rawimage);
PFN myfunctionptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem! 
It was a simple typo in the `typedef palpr_recognize_rawimage_type` line:
I forgot to add the suffix `_type` to the type declaration and hence the type and the actual pointer had the same name - which obviously would cause troubles...
If I had looked past to first error from the compiler, I would have spotted the following: `note: previous declaration` and it would have been obvious that I mesed something up in my type naming.

--> It's worth it to not to only look at the first/top error but also look at least at the second one too - as you never know, it may provide a hint too!

Comment: Seems about right.  Usually the compiler will print out the locations of both the conflicting declarations... but you have to read the actual compiler output to find that information, not just the "error list" in an IDE.

Comment: What I pasted above is the compiler output (make ouput anyways), my IDE is bash (& vim) ;)

Comment: Ok, what was on the next few lines?

Comment: I don't dre to say but it was " note: previous declaration" ... but I mistakenly just ignored everything past the first error...DUH! - you get upvotes for that!

Comment: And now you know, and you'll solve several different kinds of compile errors about a hundred times faster, because they come with the same sort of accompanying note :)

Comment: haha yes! Always look at least at the top two gcc errors - especially when the second one is a note (colored in cyan) - I agree, it should've been obvious!

Comment: You might consider making this question more useful to future readers by taking out the bits you now know aren't important (such as the `.so` file) and asking "How do I debug this kind of error?" and then adding information to your answer about reading the compiler's note.  Do keep the specific problem you had, as it makes a great example, but also describe the principle behind the solution.